# Loading nested properties via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a list of some entity with all sub-entities using LINQ but none of the methods I used works correctly. 
Here is the classes structure:

```
public class License {
   public virtual Product Product {get; set}
   . . . . . . 
   //some other License properties
   . . . . . . 
}

public class LicenseUser {
   public virtual Account User { get; set;}
   public virtual License License { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get the list of licenses for some user but each License object must contain Product as well. Any query I've tried returned list of license with "null" value in Product property.
Here are the examples LINQ queries what I've tried:

```
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
    .Include(lu => lu.License.Product)
    .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == 1)
    .Select(lu => lu.License)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
    .Include(lu => lu.License).ThenInclude(l => l.Product)
    .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == 1)
    .Select(lu => lu.License)
    .ToList();
```

I'm sure that the records we get by these queries contains valid reference to Products table (ProductId field is not null). 
I also checked the SQL generated by this LINQ request (using Diagnostic Tools). As expected it does not contains a JOIN statement for Products table.

Is there a correct way to get necessary result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit counter-intuitive, but the problem is that your `Select` is filtering out what the SQL query contains.

So you may want to force EF to include the product in the SQL too (using an anonymous object that contains both the license and its product) and then convert to a `License` collection in-memory:

```cs
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
  .Include(lu => lu.License.Product)
  .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == 1)
  .Select(lu => new { lic = lu.License, prod = lu.License.Product } )
  .AsEnumerable()  // Here we have forced the SQL to include the product too
  .Select(lu => lu.lic)
  .ToList(); // Then we select (locally) only the license for convenience 
             // (so that our collection is of type License)
             // Since the SQL Query actually loaded the products
             // the references will be ok
```

Comment: Instead of the first `.ToList()` you could probably use a `.AsEnumerable()`. In this way the second `.Select` would still be a `Enumerable.Select` instead of a `Queryable.Select` and would be executed locally.

Comment: @xanatos yep, you are right... I'm not sure one would be better than the other, but yeah, using `AsEnumerable()` sounds better, I'll edit :-)

Comment: We came to the similar solution but it's not necessary to make that additional Select after Where and return an anonymous type object. 
The list of LicenseUser object returned after Where contains all necessary info already.

Comment: Definitely. It was for convenience

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm quite new to this myself but this might give you an idea.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) MSDN article, to eagerly load multiple levels, you could try something like this:

```
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
    .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == 1)
    .Include(lu => lu.License.Select(p => p.Product))
    .ToList();
```

And checking with other examples, as Alexander said, Where() should be before Include() in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to .Select the property you want. Here you're only pulling out the License property. Try changing it to read:

```
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
    .Include(lu => lu.License.Product)
    .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == user.Id)
    .Select(lu => new { lu.License, lu.Product })
    .ToList();
```

Here you're making a new anonymous type with both of the properties you want attached. Now Licenses should contain a list of this new anonymous types that you can access by something like

```
Licenses[0].Product
```

Comment: Product is not a property of LicenseUser. It's a property of License class. I want to get the list of licenses but each license must contain the product associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround but it may lead to some inefficiency in general case.
It happens that first Include call works properly and correctly fill License.Product property in the list of LicenseUser objects. 
The problem is in last Select call which "converts" the list of LicenseUser object to the list of Licenses.
The solution - is to add "ToList" call after Where:

```
var licenses = context.LicenseUsers
    .Include(lu => lu.License.Product)
    .Where(lu => lu.User.Id == 1)
    .ToList()
    .Select(lu => lu.License)
    .ToList();
```

(I think AsEnumerable call as suggested in one of the answers will work here as well).

However I still think it's a bug in LINQ to SQL implementation for Entity Framework Core. It probably see the last Select (which gets License part of LicenseUser) and simply ignores the first Include which request to add Product information (a JOIN to Products table in terms of SQL) into result set.

Comment: The `Select` allows for optimization: if you are only going to use the `License` and its `Product` property, there's no need to retrieve the whole `LicenseUsers` table. If you use that `Select`, it'll only retrieve the needed fields.

Comment: LicenseUsers is need because of condition over that table (...User.Id == 1). I need the list of License objects in result but with all nested navigation properties (such as Product) while simple Select returns only basic License properties (without navigation ones). 
It's OK in general case but I already included Product into the query before (via .Include(lu => lu.License.Product) - so I guess it should return me "full" License object (with Product) when Select (lu => lu.License) is called.

Comment: You only need the user id for the `where` clause, no need to retrieve all the fields. And yeah, I see how this should be ironed out... something like, `if I've explicitly included a nested property using Include then it should be available if my projection includes the parent property`. You could always suggest it at: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues :-)

Comment: That's why I called my approach "inefficient". Currently I need to retrieve the list of UserLicense objects first to apply Select(ul => ul.License) to that list later.
If it had worked correctly without first ToList() - I would have no need to do that.
I will add new issues on GitHub, thank you.